# htaccess redirect root domain to subdomain with exceptions

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

i m using wordpress and want to redirect my root domain to a new subdomain and ignore urls that contains a certain string

`http://www.example.com/post.html`
To

`http://subdomain.example.com/post.html`

And exclude

`http://www.example.com/post-exclude.html`

So that i can deploy a new blog while i am redirecting the old one

What i have tried :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exclude
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it's redirecting to the main subdomain.example.com and ignoring the path

**Full Code**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exclude
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work? When you say it's "ignoring the path", is it ignoring the _exclude_ path or always _ignoring the path_ and redirecting to the root? Where in your `.htaccess` file have you placed this code? Please show the directives in-place - there might be a conflict with other directives. You should also test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. Make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Comment: It redirects to  subdomain.example.com/ instead of subdomain.example.com/some-post-exclude , while it's working when the path is not containing the exclude

Comment: also i kept the wordpress htaccess 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant code, with the directives you've added in-place. "It redirects to `subdomain.example.com/` instead" - that wouldn't seem possible with just the code you posted, so there's likely a conflict if you've put the code in the wrong place for example?

Comment: i have posted the full code

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com  [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exclude
> RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
> ```

The WordPress front-controller conflicts with your redirect and ultimately causes a redirect to `/index.php`. (Although that is not strictly the same as `/` - as you've stated - maybe there is something else that removes the `index.php` part, if it's not present in the resulting URL?)

When you initially request `/post-exclude.html`, the `RewriteCond` directive prevents the redirect, but after the request is *internally* rewritten to `/index.php` (by the WordPress front-controller below), processing then loops which then triggers the redirect to `/index.php` (the homepage). The internal rewrite results in the `REQUEST_URI` server variable being updated to `/index.php` (whilst the visible URL remains as `/post-exclude.html`).

In other words, when you request `/post-exclude.html`:

1. Redirect code is bypassed because of the `RewriteCond` (condition) directive.
2. Request is internally rewritten to `/index.php` (by the WordPress front-controller)
3. The rewrite engine starts over... (as it does when the URL is rewritten)
4. Now the redirect triggers since it is checking against `/index.php`, not `/post-exclude.html` (whilst the visible URL remains as `/post-exclude.html`).
5. Redirects to `http://subdomain.example.com/index.php`.

You can avoid this second internal rewrite triggering the redirect by making sure you only target the initial request in the redirect. You can do this by either checking against `THE_REQUEST` instead (which contains the first line of the HTTP request headers) or the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable (which is empty on the initial request and set to "200" - as in 200 OK HTTP status - after the first successful rewrite).

You should also avoid manually editing the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers as this is maintained by WordPress and your manual edits could be overwritten in a future update.

The redirect should go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` line.

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exclude

Note that this condition excludes any URL that simply contains `exclude` (case-sensitive) anywhere in the requested URL. Whereas the example you posted looks quite specific. Note that if you only want to exclude a single URL, you don't need an additional condition as this can all be done in the `RewriteRule` directive.

Try the following instead:

```
# Redirect to subdomain.example.com, excluding some URL(s)
# NB: REDIRECT_STATUS - Check the initial request only (not the rewritten request)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exclude
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

As noted in comments, test with 302 (temporary) redirects and make sure your browser cache is cleared.

Comment: It's not working for me, it's not excluding url that contains "post-exclude"

Comment: Ah, I think it's the rewritten URL (by the WordPress front-controller) that is being redirected. The issue is that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is updated after the internal rewrite, so `/post-exclude.html` ends up being redirected to `/index.php`. I've updated/rewritten my answer.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: I just needed the same and for me it works.
So, thank you.
*Now I need to also show the url of the root domain while having access to the subdomain.*